# How to load 3d models in forge viewer which have been uploaded into Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC) docs?

Tags: autodesk-forge

1. I uploaded a 3D revit (.rvt) file into ACC docs and managed to get the item's urn.
2. I also initialized a forge viewer with access token obtained using client ID and secret generated by the application which was created by an account with license in the same ACC environment.

I couldn't load the 3d model with the viewer initialized by the access token because onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:4 was given.

May I know what's the cause of this problem and how do I load my revit file in forge viewer which has been uploaded into ACC docs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a tutorial that explains how to access hubs here : [Hubs browser](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/)

I believe the error code you received is `403 Access denied`. To resolve this, you will need to provide access to your app in the Account Admin. You can find instructions on how to do this in this link: [Manage access to docs](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/manage-access-to-docs/).

Please note that the page describes how to provide access for BIM360 projects, but as far as I know, the process is the same for ACC projects.

Comment: it works now, we also found out that the '/' in model urn has to be replaced with '_' . Thank you